# Is there a common method that returns distance and angle from vector coordinates?

Tags: .net, math, vector-graphics

I need to get angle (0~359.99°) and distance from Vector2. Is there a common method for that somewhere in Math or XNA namespaces?

I'm not looking for a custom implementation, but an "official" one. It appears they are generally faster than custom ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vector2.Length` method returns the length of the vector (i.e. what you've called "distance").

To find the angle, use `Math.Atan2(P.Y, P.X)`.

This angle will be measured in radians anti-clockwise relative to the positive X-axis (i.e. standard euclidian coordinates).  Multiply the result by `180 / Math.PI` to convert it to degrees.